# How to remove folders from Bittorrent Sync

Tags: macos, mac, bittorrent, bittorrent-sync

We're starting to use BT Sync to distribute files across our network. The problem is we would like to remove old shares from the main 'server machine'.

With the application on the Mac there seems to be no obvious way of doing this, is there a command that can be run to remove the older unused files?

Answer (score 1):

On the BitTorrent Mac app their is an option to disconnect folders from synching across the network, hover over the folder you want to remove and to the very right there is a ... icon. Click on that and there is an option that says Disconnect. Here's a screenshot: [image]

But to delete/remove individual files you should just be able to delete them from the folder and the changes will sync across the network.